# magento contact email attachment, no attachment received

Tags: php, xml, email, magento

I am trying to create a magento module contact page that allow customer to attach file. I followed this tutorial of [magephsycho](http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/adding-upload-field-in-contact-form-and-send-as-attachment/) and created my own module however I am receiving blank email. Upon searching on google I found this [stackexchange question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/62453/attach-a-file-on-contact-form) and modify the IndexController.php. I am now recieving email with content but no attachment.

I am new to magento and I don't know what was wrong.

this is my html code:

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getFormAction(); ?>" id="contactForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" type="hidden" value="2000000" />
<input name="fileattachment" id="fileattachment" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('FileAttachment') ?>" placeholder="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Upload File') ?>" value="fileattachment" class="input-text" type="file" />
```

This is my config.xml saved in app/code/local/Attachment/Eattachment/etc

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <contacts>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Attachment_Eattachment before="Mage_Contacts">Attachment_Eattachment</Attachment_Eattachment>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </contacts>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

This is the code I replace in the IndexController.php that is saved on app/code/local/Attachment/Eattachment/controllers

```
if(file_exists($attachmentFilePath)){
    mailTemplate->getMail()->createAttachment(
        file_get_contents($attachmentFilePath),
        Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
        Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
        Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
        $fileName
    );
}
```

Finally, this is the config.xml that introduces the module to magento saved on app/etc/modules

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Attachment_Eattachment>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Attachment_Eattachment>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Update: This is the code from the admin transactional email

```
Name: {{var data.name}}
Email: {{var data.email}}
Telephone: {{var data.telephone}}
PollQuestions: {{var data.pollquestions}}
OtherSpecify: {{var data.othersSpecify}}
FileAttachment: {{var data.fileattachment}}
Comment: {{var data.comment}}
```

I hope I gave useful information. As of now I don't know what was going on. I'm not sure if I save the file in the proper location.

My problem is that I am not recieving any email attachedment sent in contact us page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a month since I post this question. For the mean time I move to other phase of my project before I solve this problem.

I found the problem from the contact us extension that I have installed.

To solve it, I uninstalled the extension and modify my code

MODIFICATION:

1. No need to include the input field inside the Transactional Email page. This is the modified code.

   Name: {{var data.name}}
   Email: {{var data.email}}
   Telephone: {{var data.telephone}}
   PollQuestions: {{var data.pollquestions}}
   OtherSpecify: {{var data.othersSpecify}}
   Comment: {{var data.comment}}
2. I replace the controller code from above to this

   if(file_exists($attachmentFilePath)){
                       $fileContents = file_get_contents($attachmentFilePath);

   ```
                   $attachment   = $mailTemplate->getMail()->createAttachment($fileContents);

                   $attachment->filename = $fileName;
               }
   ```

The code works and I can now receive email attachment.

Hope this helps others.